# Q: F#: Split String to Array [simple]

Tags: arrays, split, f#

Yello,
Here I am, friday noon, trying to break one of the Euler problems.

> Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.
>
> 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
>   46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
>   74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
>   91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
>   23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
>   and so on..

I decided to put all lines of numbers in a string.

```
let numString = 
"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250"
```

Next step *(instead of creating an int array then alt+shift add quotations and semicolons)* is to split all lines to an int array. *(later referred to as intArray)*

So this is where i have some problems. How does one simply split the string array to an integer array?

Lastly I want to sum up the first 10 rows

```
let sum = intArray |> Seq.map bigint.Parse |> Seq.take(10) |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: [| '\n' |]
|> numString.Split 
|> Seq.map bigint.Parse
|> Seq.sum
|> string
|> Seq.take 10 
|> Seq.fold(fun acc x -> acc + string x) ""
|> printfn "%s" -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/CF0iGB

Comment: but try your best to do not using a bigint !

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to split your string to get the numbers of each of the lines. Then if what you want is to change the array to a character array there is a built in function to do so:

```
let charArray = splitString.ToCharArray()
```

You can then convert each character to an integer with something like this:

```
let intArray = charArray |> Array.map( fun i -> int(System.Char.GetNumericValue(i)))
```

I get:

```
val intArray : int [] =
  [|3; 7; 1; 0; 7; 2; 8; 7; 5; 3; 3; 9; 0; 2; 1; 0; 2; 7; 9; 8; 7; 9; 7; 9; 9;
    8; 2; 2; 0; 8; 3; 7; 5; 9; 0; 2; 4; 6; 5; 1; 0; 1; 3; 5; 7; 4; 0; 2; 5; 0|]
```

Comment: Doesn't that convert '3' for example into 51 or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: you can write a little "prettier": let intArray = charArray |> Array.map(System.Char.GetNumericValue >> int)

Comment: @Ringil Yes, it does. Sorry, my mistake. `Seq.map (string >> Int32.Parse)`, then ;)

Comment: @Mark Seemann, then maybe is better so: `Seq.map(string >> int)` ;)

Comment: Oh that >> operator is pretty cool. Thanks I learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

That's Project Euler problem 13. I think the point of those problems is that you try to solve it on your own...

A string is nothing but a character array...can you go from here?

```
"828282" |> Seq.map char
val it : seq<char> = seq ['8'; '2'; '8'; '2'; ...]
```

It's unclear from your question if you want to solve the original problem or a new one (first 10 rows). Good luck.